# Build a dynamic interface for Object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an JSON Object received from an api call and the Object will have multiple values but all of type string. How to I write an Interface for such an Object in the shortest way.
I mean I can write and Interface with 100 keys whose type is string. But is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `interface MyInterface {
  [key: string]: string;
}` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)(a utility type in typescript):

```
const info: Record<string, string> = {
  name: "Bruce Wayne",
  address: "Bat Cave"
};
```

you can use it in your service like this:

```
class MyService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  callApi() {
    return this.http.get<Record<string, string>>(url);
  }
}
```